# How to call lua functions from corona PluginLibrary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, lua, coronasdk

I am a iOS Developer, New to Corona. I have Corona Enterprise License and developing plugin for corona. I have two questions-

1. How to set delegate in pluginLibrary.mm for any call backs from my objective-C Class/library?
2. How to call a lua function from pluginLibrary.mm?

Comment: any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Communications between native and Lua can be done by passing function parameters that come in on the Lua state stack, or by events sent between the two.  See these two tutorials:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/03/18/tutorial-corona-enterprise-quickstart-ios/
http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/04/22/tutorial-image-printing-via-corona-enterprise-ios/

This should show you the basics for communicating between Lua and Native.